# How to run these two queries simultaneously?

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, prepared-statement

**UPDATED PHP**

```
    <?php 
    $result = $sth->fetchAll();
    print_r($result); //or var_dump($result); for more info
    foreach($result as $row){
        print_r($row);
    }   
    ?>
```

**On the SQL View:**

```
$pdo = new PDO($h1, $u, $p);
$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$sth = $pdo->prepare('
SELECT uFName, uLName, listTitle, listPropPrice, listCmt, listDt
FROM User U, Listing L
WHERE U.uID = L.uID
;');
$sth->execute(array());

#GET Merchant (Seller) Info and Listings Offered On
$pdo2 = new PDO($h1, $u, $p);
$pdo2->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$sth2 = $pdo2->prepare('
SELECT mFName, mLName, moAmt, moDtOff
FROM Merchant M, MerchantOffer MO, Listing L
WHERE M.mID = MO.mID 
AND L.listID = MO.listID
;');
$sth2->execute(array());
```

How do I run `$sth` and `$sth2` within the same `WHILE` STATEMENT?

SCHEMA
[image: imggg]

Output of Louis Code:
[image: kfgdfgdfgdf]

Comment: I've tried joing them all already (all four tables that is) and it cant differentiate one from another.

Thoughts? Suggestions? Is my schema wrong?

Comment: I can check the schema, do you have the tables?

Comment: @BookOfZeus - please see schema img above.

Comment: yes I was reading the tables and Louis came with a good solution, did you try?

Comment: Yes, I did, please see the output on his comment. How do I get that to show the offers MADE by each MERCHANT on EACH listing??

Comment: IT STILL gives all the Merchant Comments at the end of outputting it all ...see screenshot

Comment: I see from the screen shot all the information you need: xbox 360 to user Joseph with merchant John, Am I missing something?

Comment: Well, I want that to display. So it would look like Joseph Wants an Xbox 360. 
--> John Offers for $x.00

then the next Item --> Merchant "Whoever" offers $x.00

Comment: Following me??? Can you show me how to manipulate all this data??? Please :) ?

Comment: in the "foreach($result as $row) {" simply "print_r($row);" and then you will have access to the array for each row the query return. for example $row['uFName'] will display the user name etc... each key of the $row correspond to the column selected in the query;

Comment: Please see the updated php I have. I put in the `print_r($row);` how do I now show for example the uFName field??

Comment: I'd really appreciate some more help. Thanks Book

Comment: and then var_dump($row['uFName']); in the loop

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to run your queries simultaneously.

As a matter of fact, getting data from database has (or should be) nothing to do with creating HTML. Its different tasks.

So, get your data into array(s) first and then print it out in whatever manner you wish - simultaneously or checkered.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the [fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) statement, you then have a result array to iterate through at the same time of using the other while. (you'll need to keep track of a separate counter)

UPDATE:

Now I get ya, try this.

```
 //Get the listing info
  $pdo = new PDO($h1, $u, $p);
  $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
  $sth = $pdo->prepare('
    SELECT uFName, uLName, listTitle, listPropPrice, listCmt, listDt, listID
    FROM User U, Listing L
    WHERE U.uID = L.uID
  ;');
  $sth->execute(array());

  $listings = $sth->fetchAll();

  //loop through all the listings
  foreach($listings as $listing){

    echo "Listing info...<br/>";

    //grab the merchant info for the listing
    $pdo2 = new PDO($h1, $u, $p);
    $pdo2->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    $sth2 = $pdo2->prepare("
      SELECT mFName, mLName, moAmt, moDtOff
      FROM Merchant M, MerchantOffer MO, Listing L
      WHERE M.mID = MO.mID 
      AND L.listID = MO.listID
      and L.listID = {$listing['listID']}
    ;");
    $sth2->execute(array());

    //if there is only one merchant per listing, probably don't 
    //need fetchAll and can go back to single row
    $merchants = $sth2->fetchAll();
    //loop through all merchants
    foreach($merchants as $merchant){
      echo "Merchant info...<br/>";
    }
  }
```

Comment: could you show how to implement fetchall with my code? Pretty please!

Comment: This just outputs it all like: Array ( [0] => Array ( [uFName] => Joseph [0] => Joseph [uLName] => Dickinson [1] => Dickinson [listTitle] => Need Xbox 360 [2] => Need Xbox 360 [listPropPrice] => 150 [3] => 150 [listCmt] => I need one quick! [4] => I need one quick! [listDt] => 2011-09-15 [5] => 2011-09-15 [mFName] => John [6] => John [mLName] => Doe [7] => Doe [moAmt] => 149.99 [8] => 149.99 [moDtOff] => 2011-09-15 [9] => 2011-09-15 ) [1] => Array ( [uFName] => Joseph [0] => Joseph [uLName] => Dickinson [1] => Dickinson [listTitle] => Need Xbox 360 [2] => Need Xbox 360 [listPropPrice] =>

Comment: How do I get it to show each LISTING with the merchants who have submited to each listing???

Comment: Please see the output of your CODE, I want it to read the uFName, uLName, listTitle, listPropPrice, then show all the mFName, mLName, moAmt that correspond to that listing. Does that make sense??

Comment: I think I get ya now does that make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

I have update Louis code because I think it can better handle.

```
//Get the listing info
$pdo = new PDO($h1, $u, $p);
$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$sth = $pdo->prepare('
  SELECT uFName, uLName, listTitle, listPropPrice, listCmt, listDt, listID
  FROM User U, Listing L
  WHERE U.uID = L.uID');
$sth->execute();

$listings = $sth->fetchAll();

//Prepare the statement to grab the merchant info for the listing
$pdo2 = new PDO($h1, $u, $p);
$pdo2->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$sth2 = $pdo2->prepare('
  SELECT mFName, mLName, moAmt, moDtOff
  FROM Merchant M, MerchantOffer MO, Listing L
  WHERE M.mID = MO.mID 
  AND L.listID = MO.listID
  and L.listID = :listid');

$sth2->bindParam(':listid', $listing['listID'], PDO::PARAM_INT);

//loop through all the listings
foreach($listings as $listing){

    echo "Listing info...<br/>";

    // Executed prepared statement (the parameter is updated automatically)
    $sth2->execute();

    //if there is only one merchant per listing, probably don't 
    //need fetchAll and can go back to single row
    $merchants = $sth2->fetchAll();
    //loop through all merchants
    foreach($merchants as $merchant){
       echo "Merchant info...<br/>";
    }
}
```

The changes are:

- Use bindParam to set the values (if you use PDO it's better to use it, or bindValue).
- Only make one prepared statement to optimize it, and not one for each iteration.
- Remove ';' from sql, php manual say that sql sentence must be without it.

I can't comment, because it I have made a new answer instead of comment or edit Louis answer.